# Should I just make sure a value is within its range during a main loop or fix it when it supposedly changes?

Tags: c#

Currently I have this code all throughout my program in many places such as form resizing events, splitter moving events, document size changes, et cetera:

```
hsc.Value = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(hsc.Value, 0, hsc.Maximum - hsc.LargeChange + 1);
vsc.Value = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(vsc.Value, 0, vsc.Maximum - vsc.LargeChange + 1);
```

I'm wondering whether or not it would be better to just put it in a main loop because my program has a drawing code that is called whenever the application goes idle (very often).

The disadvantage of having this code in events is because it is code repetition and I might miss an event. The disadvantage of having it in the loop is that it may not be needed each loop and it is wasted processor cycles. However, it may be premature optimization because it probably would not be noticeable to the end-user.

Comment: Cant you add tis 2 lines in a method and call that method from every events? That way you dont miss nor duplicate code

Comment: Yes but I doubt it'd be worth it because I have to do this in other classes as well where I don't have access to a reference of the form and only the scrollbar controls.

Comment: Well its never good design to alter the main forms controls in another sub classes. Rather do your core logic in other classes and get the result back, alter your UI elements only in the Forms main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What framework are you using? (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, etc)

If it's in every Window / Form / View / UserControl then you might consider putting this functionality in a base class and pointing all these events to event handlers in the base class.

Neither of your solutions seem correct - you shouldn't be redrawing in a 'main loop' if nothing has changed, and you shouldn't be copy/pasting duplicated code throughout your app.